# how to add "$i", for loop in sed command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

```
for (( i=30; i<=44; i++))
do
sed -i '28s/0.340d0/0."$i"0d0/' 1.txt 
mv 1.txt "$i".txt     
done
```

but while executing, it is not working. In the sed command "$i" loop not working. Please help. I want a digit that is given as 0.340do in 28 lines in the 1.txt file should replace like 0.30d0 to 0.440d0 in copied files.

Comment: What does line 28 in your `1.txt` originally look like?

Comment: 28 line looks lik: rmin=0.340d0

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `'` quote makes it so the variable gets interpreted literally as `$i` instead of 30, 31, 32, etc.

I've made the change below wrapping the entire sed expression in `"` quotes:

```
for (( i=30; i<=44; i++))
do
sed "s/0.340d0/0.${i}0d0/g" 1.txt > temp.txt
cp temp.txt "$i".txt     
done
```

Comment: Assuming the original `1.txt` file has a line 28 that is `0.340d0`, this would be changed to `0.300d0` in the first iteration.  Every other iteration would fail to modify that line since it's no longer `0.340d0`.  There is _really_ no point in using `-i` with `sed` here. Just do `sed '...' file >newfile`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: What if the line 28 contains `0a340d00b340d00c340d0` etc?

Comment: @choroba That is up to the answer owner to take into account.

Comment: no formate is that only, we can make it to 0.34 to 0.30, 31, 32...0.44.

Comment: this code is not working

Comment: 28 line looks lik:  rmin=0.340d0

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I made an update to the answer

Comment: also, I think you should `cp` the file instead of `mv` because by moving it, the sed should fail on the next pass because the file doesn't exists anymore. I made the change to cp based on the snippet in play

Comment: @EWJ00 Thanks alot. It is working now

Comment: @daizy123 I doubt that it's working with the  code as it it written right now.  The `sed` command is outputting its result to the terminal.

Comment: no, I have modified as sed "s/0.340d0/0.${i}0d0/g" 1.txt > 1a.txt

Comment: so that's why it is working, we can do -i also

Comment: Still wouldn't work as you're changing the original file.  If you change all the `0.340d0` strings in that file to `0.300d0` in the first iteration of the loop, how can you expect to get anything else than `0.300d0` in any other iteration?

Comment: updated to redirect to a file with no sed -i

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues in your code:

1. You use a single quoted string as tho `sed` expression, stopping the shell from expanding the variable in the replacement part of the `s///` command.
2. You change your original `1.txt` file in place, so even if the variable was expanded by the shell, the pattern would not match on the second time through the loop (since the file was modified by the previous iteration).
3. You move the `1.txt` file away in the first iteration, which would make the `sed` command fail with a "No such file or directory" error in each subsequent iteration.

Fixing these three issues:

```bsh
for number in {30..44}; do
    sed '28 s/0\.340d0/0.'"$number"'0d0/' 1.txt >"$number.txt"
done
```

Note that I'm also making sure that the dot in the pattern is matching a *literal* dot and not any character (which is what `.` would do if it wasn't escaped as `\.` or used as `[.]`).  I'm still using a single quote for your `sed` expression, but I'm breaking out of it temporarily to introduce a double quoted value from the shell variable `number`.

The result of the `sed` command is written to a filename named using the `number` variable.

Instead of addressing the line with its line number, you could also use the fact that it starts with the string `rmin=` (assuming that's the *only* line starting with this string):

```bsh
for number in {30..44}; do
    sed 's/^rmin=.*/rmin=0.'"$number"'0d0/' 1.txt >"$number.txt"
done
```

The same thing could be done a bit neater with `awk`:

```bsh
for number in {30..44}; do
    awk -v num="$number" 'FNR == 28 { printf "rmin=0.%.2d0d0\n", num; next }; 1' 1.txt >"$number.txt"
done
```

This has the advantage that it would insert the number correctly, even if it was less than 10 (creating `0.020d0` instead of `0.20d0` for `2`, for example).

Or, matching `rmin=` at the start of a line:

```bsh
for number in {30..44}; do
    awk -v num="$number" '/^rmin=/ { printf "rmin=0.%.2d0d0\n", num; next }; 1' 1.txt >"$number.txt"
done
```